# Hide Submenu on Navigation when not On hover

Tags: html, css, nav

I have a navigation menu that doesn't work properly when you hover over the submenus.

When you hover over Online Payments --> Magazine Renewals the submenu displays properly but once I am not hover on Magazine Renewals it still shows.

My question is, How do I hide that submenu when is not being hover.

Here is the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cgzUm/19/

```
<nav id="nav">
    <div class="inner">          
        <ul id="show_menu">
            <li class="parent"><a href="/contact/">Contact</a> </li>

            <li class="parent" style="background-color: #a61f2e;"><a href="/tagtile/">Online Payments</a>
                <ul class="smallcolumn">
                    <li><a href="/weddings/"><em>&diams;</em> Magazine Renewals</a>
                    <ul class = "submenu">
                            <li><a href="#"><em>&diams;</em>HTML</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><em>&diams;</em>CSS</a></li>
                        </ul></li>
                    <li><a href="/weddings-edwardian/"><em>&diams;</em> Other Content</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/weddings-edwardian/"><em>&diams;</em> Content</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/weddings-edwardian/"><em>&diams;</em> Testing </a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
 nav { background: black;  border-top:1px #fff solid; border-bottom:2px #fff solid; }
 nav { background: black;  border-top:1px #fff solid; border-bottom:2px #fff solid; }
 #nav { position:relative; z-index: 999; background: # 000;}
 #nav ul { float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0;  width: 100%;  display: block;  list-   style: none;  border-left:2px #fff solid;  }
 #nav li { float:left;  display: block; position: relative; border-right:2px #fff solid;  }
   /*Text properties for navigation*/
   #nav a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
 border-bottom: 1px solid white;
 padding: 0.7em 1em;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 0;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.4);

 }
    #nav a:hover { background:#fff; color: #000;  color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); }
    #nav a.active { background:#c4940e; color:#fff; box-shadow:0px 6px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset;}

    #nav li:hover { background:#fff; } 
    #nav li:hover a { color: #000;  color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); text-shadow:none; }
    #nav ul li ul { display:none; position:absolute; background:#fff; width:440px; top:40px; left:-2px; box-shadow:4px 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);  padding:0.6em 0 0.8em 0; /*visibility: hidden;*/ -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
        -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
        transition: all 0.2s ease; }
    #nav ul li:hover ul { display:block;   /*visibility: visible;*/}
#nav ul li ul li { float:left; width:50%; background:none !important; border:0; color:#eeeedd; }
#nav ul li ul li a { display:inline-block; background:none !important; text- indent:0;   text-align:left; border:0; padding:0.2em 1em;  }
#nav ul li ul li a:hover { opacity:1; } 
#nav ul li ul li:hover { background:none; }


.ie7 #nav ul li:hover ul { left:0; }
 .ie7 #nav ul li ul li a { padding:0.2em 0; text-indent:1em; }

 #nav ul li ul.smallcolumn      { width:220px; }
 #nav ul li ul.smallcolumn li   { width:100%; }
  /*diamond in the menu*/
  #nav i, #nav em { color:#9f2537;  }
 #nav ul li ul li a:hover i,
 #nav ul li ul li a:hover em { color:#011c3a;  }

  /*submenu*/
  #nav ul li ul li:hover ul { top:0;  left:100%; position: absolute; width:100%; background-color: #fff; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 28 in your JSFiddle sets display: block for all ULs in a menu. This also applies to your submenu and overwrites its display: none;

So change line 28 to the following:

```
#nav ul li:hover > ul { display:block;   /*visibility: visible;*/}
```

">" selects only ULs that are first-level children of the hovered LI.

Answer (score 0):

Line 28 (CSS)

```
#nav ul li:hover > ul { display:block;   /*visibility: visible;*/}
```

and delete last line

```
#nav ul li ul li ul  {  display:inherit; }
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nidzix/cgzUm/29/